# Cannot make foreign key field nullable with Sequel Pro

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, sequelpro

I'm having a defined relation to my user table as foreign key, but they don't necessarily need to be set. I.e. there must not be a related record.

In my MySQL editor (Sequel Pro) I cannot make the addressId "allow null". It ignores the input. Im using newest version.

When I create a new entry in the User table without an addressId, it says "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails...". But I want to be able to add a User without an Address! Is that possible?

Or should I simply remove the foreign keys? What is the drawback of that?

```
CREATE TABLE `User1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` char(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `addressId` int(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `activated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastLogin` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`addressId`),
  KEY `FK_User_Locale` (`localeId`),
  KEY `FK_User_Address` (`addressId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_User_Address` FOREIGN KEY (`addressId`) REFERENCES `Address` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: I would remove the foreign key contraint.. IMO using a database to enforce referential integrity is a waste of resources. Plus when you rename columns and tables its a nightmare. Writing strong server scripts is a much better approach.

Comment: @dano Columns and tables should never be renamed. A far worse nightmare is learning the script you thought was strong is actually weak and your data has lost integrity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you disable [foreign_key_checks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks) by setting to foreign_key_checks=0?

Else you may `DROP` the constraint if it does't suit your requirements!

> If set to 1 (the default), foreign key constraints for InnoDB tables
>   are checked. If set to 0, they are ignored. Disabling foreign key
>   checking can be useful for reloading InnoDB tables in an order
>   different from that required by their parent/child relationships.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense then, to just remove the foreign key declarations alltogether?

Comment: Yeah its your wish!. If you don't need any referential integrity you may DROP it. Anyway, I've edited my answer accordingly.